# Is it possible to swap the order of Code Action menu items in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

[image]

Is it possible to configure the order of Code Action menu items in VS Code? If not, can I somehow prevent Copilot from adding Code Action menu items while keeping Copilot itself enabled?

I have zero interest in having Copilot fix anything. Yet it's options have become the first in the context menu and it is disrupting my flow.

I've checked the config options but I didn't see anything related to the Code Action menu under Copilot. Nor did I notice any general context menu configuration that would allow for sorting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that you can't- at least- not on the user side at the time of this writing.

From reading https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126393, my understanding is that sort order for a single [Code Action provider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CodeActionProvider%3CT%3E) is based on the the order as given by that provider. The only "change" to that order is when grouping happens by severity and type (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34664. TL;DR errors go to the top, and actions are grouped by type automatically).

I see some related issue tickets:

- [[Feature Request] Allow sort order of code actions from multiple providers #152845](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152845)
- [Allow sort order of code actions from multiple providers to be influenced
  #62267](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/62267)

Unfortunately, both of those issue tickets are closed (one kind of for historical reasons, and one for not receiving enough community support within the allotted time window). I think you can [raise a new feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) (raise it again, or raise it with modifications you'd want).

An alternative route if you only care about one particular extension's Code Actions would be to raise a feature-request to that specific extension's maintainers asking for a setting to configure the sort order of its contributed code actions.

Note: For your reference / learning purposes, I found that info by googling "`github vscode issues order code actions`".

---

As for the specific behaviour of the Copilot extension, the asker raised an issue ticket: [Allow for configuration of code action order #194213](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194213), and the maintainers responded by making a change such that Copilot actions are automatically demoted in the quick fix widget ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194213#issuecomment-1756022159)). The change is available in the latest VS Code Insiders, and will eventually make it into the stable release unless they decide against it later. A further change was made in [Placing AI code actions always at the bottom of the quick fix menu #195353](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/195353). The milestone for that change is the October 2023 release.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.